# Don't auto-extend c/c++ trailing comments

Tags: comments, filetype-c++, filetype-c

Edit this C++ excerpt:

```
// line 1
int xxxxxxxx = 0; // line 2
int yyyyyyyy = 0;
```

When the cursor is in line 1 and you hit `o` to insert a line below it, Vim conveniently starts the new line with another `//`  comment.

When the cursor is in line 2 and you do the same, the new line begins with a comment aligned with line 2's trailing comment:

```
// line 1
int xxxxxxxx = 0; // line 2
                  // 
int yyyyyyyy = 0;
```

This is unhelpful if you prefer block (multiline) comments to not be deeply indented. A trailing comment is more likely to be two or three words sufficient unto itself, than the unfinished start of a long paragraph.

Can inserting below line 2 begin *without* an automatically added comment mark (like inserting below line 3), while preserving line 1's behavior?

In C++, `set comments?` reports `comments=sO:* -,mO:*  ,exO:*/,s1:/*,mb:*,ex:*/,:///,://`, and `set formatoptions?` reports `croql`. This is for vim 9.0 patches 1-1424, on both Ubuntu 22.04 and macOS 13.4.1.

(The offending line-2 behavior happens with `//` also in C, but not with `#` in bash, php, ruby, etc; and not with `//` in php).

Comment: what is your `formatoptions`? (this never happens to me)

Comment: There is `/` you can add to `formatoptions` that should do the thing for you. Check `:h fo-table` for details.

Comment: @MaximKim I'd accept that as an answer.  `set formatoptions=croql/` worked on both mac and ubuntu.  (Put (something like) that in my vimrc, or elsewhere?)

Comment: Put it in your `vimrc` to have it everywhere or in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/cpp.vim` if you want this option only for C++ files (likewise `c.vim` for C).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `/` to `formatoptions`

```
set formatoptions+=/
```

as described in `:h fo-table`:

```
                            *fo-o*
o   Automatically insert the current comment leader after hitting 'o' or
    'O' in Normal mode.  In case comment is unwanted in a specific place
    use CTRL-U to quickly delete it. |i_CTRL-U|
                            *fo-/*
/   When 'o' is included: do not insert the comment leader for a //
    comment after a statement, only when // is at the start of the line.
```

Answer (score 2):

When `cindent` is on, the comment formatting options are somehow overridden by the `cindent` and `formatoptions` settings.

`:help format-comments`

```
Enabling 'cindent' will override the alignment flags in many cases.
Reindenting using a different method like |gq| or |=| will not consult
alignment flags either. The same behaviour can be defined in those other
formatting options. One consideration is that 'cindent' has additional options
for context based indenting of comments but cannot replicate many three piece
indent alignments.  However, 'indentexpr' has the ability to work better with
three piece comments.
```

One solution to this problem is to turn off `cindent`:

```
set nocindent
```

And search for an alternative way to indent `c` and `c++` code...

This [indent script](https://github.com/slara/vimfiles/blob/master/indent/cpp.vim) could be an example of solution for that problem.

Or even better, as suggested by @MaximKim:

```
set formatoptions+=/
```

Comment: I can't reproduce `cindent` to have an impact on this issue. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: @Friedrich, I can reproduce the issue with both Vim 9.0 and Neovim 0.9.4. But with both if I set `cindent` to false (`:set nocindent`) the "problem" is gone (actually no comment continuation is done).

Comment: I have Vim 9.0 (patches 1-1968). I start with `vim --clean foo.cpp` and comment continuation is done after both `:set cindent` and `:set nocindent`. Very strange :-/

Comment: Also in the case of a line like `int a = 3; // foo`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. That's why I'm puzzled.